# An Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp variables changed another variables value

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gcc, eigen

I wrote a program, but I found an Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp variables changed another variables value, even through they are not involved!

This program ran well at Win10x64, but failed at Ubuntu18.04 with gcc7.5.0.

Environment:

`$ gcc --version gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0`
Eigen v3.4.0

My code:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <eigen3/Eigen/Core>

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

int main(){
    auto a = Vector3d(1,2,3)*0.1;
    auto b = Vector3d(-10,-9,-8)*100.0;

    cout<<a.transpose()<<endl;

    assert(a.isApprox(Vector3d(0.1,0.2,0.3)));

    cout<<"pass"<<endl;
    return 0;

}
```

Expected:
a is {0.1,0.2,0.3};
b is {-1000,-900,-800};

But my code output:

```
$ ./TestEigen 
  -1 -0.9 -0.8
TestEigen: /home/xxxxxx/program/TestEigen/main.cpp:14: int main(): Assertion `a.isApprox(Vector3d(0.1,0.2,0.3))' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The a got {-1,-0.9,-0.8}!

Why such a strenge result I got?

Comment: You are assigning an expression to an `auto` variable, don't do that: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPitfalls.html#title3

Comment: @chtz thank you! I have known what error is this. Even though I still don't know why this result occurred by "auto".